# When I try and use contact form 7 it breaks my page

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using the following code to add a contact form to my template, but this code as is breaks the page. It just shows a white page when I add this code. Am I doing it wrong.

```
<?php
[contact-form-7 id="181" title="Contact form 1"]
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well without more code it's hard to tell but one thing is you are wrapping a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) with php tags. My guess is you have error logs turned off or you'd see `Santax error unexpected '[' on line XXX`

If you are using the post/page editor you want to use`[contact-form-7 id="181" title="Contact form 1"]` (see no php tags)

If you really want to use php tags (or embed the form into a template) you could do something like

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="181" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>`

If that doesn't help please post more code.